# Saving Python Results as .txt File

Tags: python, matrix, save

I have this code (`unique_set=np.random.choice([0, 1], (10000, 10, 10, 10))`) that generates 10000 3D binary matrices and I'm attempting to save the result as a .txt file. The other similar questions I checked were either trying to write a print statement to a file or were noticeably different. I tried so many of the solutions like the one below, but none of them worked.

```
sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")
print(unique_set)
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to save to the text file? There is no natural representation for a 4-dimensional list. Why use a text-file at all?

Comment: I'm not trying to save it as a 4D list. I want all my 10000 3D matrices to be saved in a text file (comma separated). That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
import numpy as np
file = open('D:\\yourpath\\filename.txt', 'w')
unique_set=np.random.choice([0, 1], (10000, 10, 10, 10))
file.write('%s\n' %unique_set)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, please post your complete code so that problem cab be solved easily

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the number that this code returns mean? (It returns a number when compiled)

Comment: What number returned

Comment: Last time a 5-digit number, but it seems to change as I change the properties of the matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how the format of your output file should look like, this is one possibility:

```
np.savetxt("test.txt", unique_set.flatten(), delimiter=",")
```

Comment: ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 4D array instead

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Comment: Then you must be using a very special programming language where a 4-Dimensional numpy Array actually a plain python list... That is not really clear from your question

Comment: I appreciate your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

You can store as JSON text file (preserves it being a 4D array)
--[storing Numpy N dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495777/can-numpy-savetxt-be-used-on-n-dimensional-ndarrays-with-n2)

```
import json

with open('"test.txt"', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(unique_set.tolist(), f)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Comment: @AmirChamanara--did you assign `unique_set=np.random.choice([0, 1], (10000, 10, 10, 10))`?  Is so, unique_set is a numpy array and we are using it's tolist method [reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).  This saves the 4D array structure as nested lists.  If you just want a 1D array of the values then use MSpiller answer which uses np.savetext of unique_set.flatten().  Note unique_set.flatten() also depends upon this being a numpy array.

Comment: @AmirChamanara--what do you get from `print(type(unique_set))`?  If should be `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.